# 式を計算する電卓を作ったところ、式に複数の演算子があるとうまく計算されない

Tags: java

一行電卓のプログラムを作成しています。"1+1"など2つの数字を使用した場合の計算は成功するのですが、数字が3つ以上（例①10+10+10、②1+1+1+1+1+1)の場合、正しく計算されません。例①の答えは10、例②の答えは3になってしまいます。下記にコードを記載ましたので、アドバイスいただけると幸いです!

———-以下コード—————

```java
package Calclator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("input numbers and operator");
        System.out.println("operator: +, -, x, ÷,%,^,r(square root)");
        System.out.println("symbol: =");
        
        while (true) {
            String[] user_input = new String[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < user_input.length; i++) {
                user_input[i] = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            }
            if (user_input[0].equals("")) { 
                System.out.println("Over");
                break;
            } else if (user_input[1].equals("")) { 
                System.err.println("Error");
                continue;
            }
        
            String[] ops = { "+", "-", "×", "÷", "%", "^", "r" };

            if (!(user_input[1].equals(ops[6])) && user_input[3].equals("")) {
                int calc;
                int digit1 = Integer.parseInt(user_input[0]);
                int digit2 = Integer.parseInt(user_input[2]);
                int ans = calc(digit1, digit2, user_input);
                System.out.println(ans);
            } else if (user_input[1].equals(ops[6]) && user_input[3].equals("")) {
                double calc2;
                double digit3 = Double.parseDouble(user_input[0]);
                double result = calc2(digit3, user_input);
                System.out.println(result);
            } 
                
            else if (!(user_input[3].equals(""))) {
                user_input = tempArray(user_input);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < user_input.length; i++) {
                user_input[i] = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            }
            int calc;
            int digit1 = Integer.parseInt(user_input[0]);
            int digit2 = Integer.parseInt(user_input[2]);
            int digit4 = Integer.parseInt(user_input[4]);

            int interAns = calc(digit1, digit2, user_input);
            int newAns = calc4(digit4, interAns, user_input);
            System.out.println(newAns);
        }
    }

    public static int calc(int digit1, int digit2, String[] user_input) {
        if (user_input[1].equals("+")) {
            return digit1 + digit2;
        }
        if (user_input[1].equals("-")) {
            return digit1 - digit2;
        }
        if (user_input[1].equals("×")) {
            return digit1 * digit2;
        }
        if (user_input[1].equals("÷")) {
            return digit1 / digit2;
        }

        if (user_input[1].equals("%")) {
            return digit1 % digit2;
        }
        if (user_input[1].equals("^")) {
            return digit1 ^ digit2;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static double calc2(double digit3, String[] user_input) {
        if (user_input[1].equals("r")) {
            double A = Math.sqrt(digit3);
            return A;
        }
        return 0.0;
    }

    public static String[] tempArray(String[] user_input) {
        String[] temp_input = new String[user_input.length + 3];
        for (int i = 0; i < user_input.length; i++) {
            temp_input[i] = user_input[i];
        }
        user_input = temp_input;
        return user_input;
    }

    public static int calc4(int digit4, int interAns, String[] user_input) {
        if (user_input[3].equals("+")) {
            return interAns + digit4;
        }
        if (user_input[3].equals("-")) {
            return interAns - digit4;
        }
        if (user_input[3].equals("×")) {
            return interAns * digit4;
        }
        if (user_input[1].equals("÷")) {
            return interAns / digit4;
        }
        if (user_input[3].equals("%")) {
            return interAns % digit4;
        }
        if (user_input[3].equals("^")) {
            return interAns ^ digit4;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: あなたのプログラムを動かして1+1<Enter>を入力しましたが何も出力されません。あなたのプログラムが動いているのが判るキャプチャー画像を投稿して下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ロジックとしては長さ４の配列を用意して
とりあえず４つ読んで
num op num をこえたら（４つめが空文字列じゃなければ）

配列の長さを＋３延長して長さ７にして
num op num op num op num
までうけとれるようにしたってことでいいんですよね

ただその後の

```
            for (int i = 0; i < user_input.length; i++) {
                user_input[i] = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            }
```

の追加入力を受け取る部分で
もう１度配列の先頭からいれちゃってるので
最初に受け取った値を上書きしちゃってるのがまずいかも

```
            System.out.println("===== ここまでの入力 =====");
            for(int i = 0; i < user_input.length; i++)
                System.out.print(user_input[i]);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("==========================");
```

こんな感じのデバッグを入れてみるとわかりやすいかも

実行結果

```
java Main
input numbers and operator
operator: +, -, x, ÷,%,^,r(square root)
symbol: =
1
+
2
+
3
+
4
+
5
+
6
==== ここまでの入力 ====
3+4+5+6
========================
```

とおそらく追加で３つだけ受け取るはずが
合計１１回入力を要求されて
最初の 1 + 2 がなかったことになってます

なのでこの部分を０からじゃなく４番目以降にうめるようにすれば入力はうまくいくかと

```
            for (int i = 4; i < user_input.length; i++) {
                user_input[i] = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
            }

            System.out.println("===== ここまでの入力 =====");
            for(int i = 0; i < user_input.length; i++)
                System.out.print(user_input[i]);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("==========================");
```

実行結果

```
> java Main
input numbers and operator
operator: +, -, x, ÷,%,^,r(square root)
symbol: =
1
+
2
+
3
+
4
===== ここまでの入力 =====
1+2+3+4
======================
6
```

10 にならずに 6 にしかならないのは

```
            int digit1 = Integer.parseInt(user_input[0]);
            int digit2 = Integer.parseInt(user_input[2]);
            int digit4 = Integer.parseInt(user_input[4]);

            int interAns = calc(digit1, digit2, user_input);
            int newAns = calc4(digit4, interAns, user_input);
```

でいま 2 4 6 番目までの計算しかやってないからです

---

そもそも 1 + 2 * 3 みたいな入力が合っても 1 + (2 * 3) のように
後に入力したものを先に計算したいみたいな要件はなく
常に左側結合で (1 + 2) * 3 を計算すればいいってことですよね？

つまり 1 + 2 の時点で 3 を計算してしまって
* 3 を受け取る時点で 1 + 2 の結果だけ持ってれば入力は捨ててしまっていいわけです

なら配列を使わなくても op + digit を読んだ時点で現在の数字を更新していけばよくって
/num (op num)* "r"?/ の正規表現を受理するスタックマシンでいいんですよね
昔の計算機がそういう方式を採用してたので興味があれば「スタックマシン」とかでぐぐって調べてみてください

こんな感じで比較的シンプルに書けるしメモリにも優しいです

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("input numbers and operator");
        System.out.println("operator: +, -, x, ÷,%,^,r(square root)");
        System.out.println("symbol: =");
        
        while(true) {

            // 最初は数字確定
            int interAns = Integer.parseInt(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine());

            // 以降は op (+ num) を読んで現在の数字を更新していく
            while (true) {
                // 次は OP 確定
                String op = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

                // op が空 = 入力終了 => 現在の結果表示して最初の入力まで戻る
                if(op.equals("")) {
                    System.out.println(interAns);
                    break;
                }

                // ルートの場合だけ次の数字を要求しない
                if(op.equals("r")) {
                    System.out.println(calc2(interAns, op));
                    // 計算結果が double になってしまうのでここでおわりでいいのかな？
                    break;
                }
                // ルート以外は次の数字を読んで途中結果を更新
                else {
                    int digit = Integer.parseInt(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
                    interAns = calc4(digit, interAns, op);
                }

                // デバッグ用
                System.out.println("interAns = " + interAns);
                 
                // また次の op を読むためにループ
            }

        }
    }


    public static double calc2(double digit3, String op) {
        if (op.equals("r")) {
            double A = Math.sqrt(digit3);
            return A;
        }
        return 0.0;
    }


    public static int calc4(int digit4, int interAns, String op) {
        if (op.equals("+")) {
            return interAns + digit4;
        }
        if (op.equals("-")) {
            return interAns - digit4;
        }
        if (op.equals("×")) {
            return interAns * digit4;
        }
        if (op.equals("÷")) {
            return interAns / digit4;
        }
        if (op.equals("%")) {
            return interAns % digit4;
        }
        if (op.equals("^")) {
            return interAns ^ digit4;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

実行結果

```
> java Main
input numbers and operator
operator: +, -, x, ÷,%,^,r(square root)
symbol: =
1
+
2
interAns = 3
+
3
interAns = 6
+
4
interAns = 10

10
```

Comment: このプログラムを解析したのですか？凄いですね。私はそれを諦めました。私はこれを逆ポーランドで書き直すべきだと思います。

Comment: chicoさん
お忙しいところ、詳しく添削いただきありがとうございます。
簡潔で、とても分かりやすいです。
本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: @Katsu この回答で解決しましたら、ぜひ[回答の承認](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1735/)をなさってください。